# Rocket.rs route by subdomain

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

Is there a way to handle requests from different subdomains differently?  For example, I have `www.example.com` which I'd like to return `www.html` and `aaa.example.com` which I'd like to return `aaa.html`.

I know how to *get* the hostname, and I could always just check that and have different branches that respond to the same request and each checks for a different hostname, but that seems a bit excessive.

I was wondering if there was something like this:

```
#[get("/", host="www.example.com")]
fn index() -> &'static str {
    "www"
}

#[get("/", host="aaa.example.com")]
fn index() -> &'static str {
    "aaa"
}
```

Comment: I have no idea if that is available in Rocket, but note that that is typically done through some other part of the web stack, such as a reverse proxy (for example, nginx). Of course, if you're not using one then it's way bigger a change than a bunch of conditionals :)

Comment: Hmm yeah I'm not.  I'm learning about web servers/security and so I'm trying to build it from the group up.  Guess for now I'll just use conditionals, thanks!

Comment: You could likely build a request guard, given that you already know how to get the hostname.

Comment: @vcapra1 I would also like this feature in rocket. Since you say "I know how to get the hostname", could you add an example to your question where you show this?

Comment: @olehermanse Check out my gist here https://gist.github.com/vcapra1/2dc30575f798d9702433a6c57882862b.  Basically you have an argument for each route that implements FromRequest and outputs success when it matches, but forwards when it doesn't (this example is a minimal example and I haven't tested it but it should work, just replace the actual URLs with the ones you want, etc).

Comment: @vcapra1 Thanks! I managed to get it working in a slightly different way, see my comment on your gist: https://gist.github.com/vcapra1/2dc30575f798d9702433a6c57882862b#gistcomment-2922765